# Parent class select query error + Insert parent/children together : Spring 4 Hibernate ORM

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, annotations

I have two issues that is blocking my development for some time:

1. When I do this in my controller, it only works if I do a Jackson (com.fasterxml.jackson) @JsonIgnore on the parent class references in the children:

Why is there such a behaviour? Is it something that should be expected?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Tenant data(@RequestParam("id") Long id) {
    return tenantRepo.get(id);
}
```

(If I do not give @JsonIgnore, it goes into an infinte loop of sorts of a parent inside a child and throws error)

2.
Now I pass this json to the below controller endpoint:

```
{
  "type": "Student",
  "numOfPeople": "1",
  "tenantMembers": [
    {
      "firstName": "Chris",
      "lastName": "C"
    }
  ],
  "tenantDetails": {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "J",
    "email" "xyz@gmail.com"
  }
}

 @RequestMapping(value = "/set", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        @ResponseBody
        public Tenant test(@RequestBody Tenant tenant) {
            return tenantRepo.save(tenant);
        }
```

(and I get SQLERROR. I tried removing the foreign key constraints, but still the same issue.)

My Parent Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tenant")
public class Tenant {

@GeneratedValue
@Id
private Long id;

private String type;

@Column(name = "num_of_people")
private String numOfPeople;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "tenant", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<TenantMember> tenantMembers;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "tenant", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private TenantDetails tenantDetails;
```

TenantMember child class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tenant_member")
public class TenantMember {
@GeneratedValue
@Id
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "tenant_id")
@JsonIgnore
private Tenant tenant;

@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;
```

TenanatDetails child class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tenant_details")
public class TenantDetails {
@GeneratedValue
@Id
private Long id;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "tenant_id")
@JsonIgnore
private Tenant tenant;

@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;

private String email;
```

This is my Hibernate config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Value("${jdbc.driverClassName}")
    private String driverClassName;
    @Value("${jdbc.url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${jdbc.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${jdbc.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String hibernateDialect;
    @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
    private String hibernateShowSql;
    @Value("${hibernate.format_sql}")
    private String hibernateFormatSql;


    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder builder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource());
        builder.scanPackages(new String[]{"com.example.demo.core.db.models"})
                .addProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return builder.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        //properties.put("hibernate.dialect", hibernateDialect);
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", hibernateShowSql);
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", hibernateFormatSql);
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
    }
}
```

Stack trace for issue 1:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.example.demo.core.db.models.Tenant.tenantMembers, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: com.example.demo.core.db.models.Tenant[&quot;tenantMembers&quot;]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.example.demo.core.db.models.Tenant.tenantMembers, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: com.example.demo.core.db.models.Tenant[&quot;tenantMembers&quot;])
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:272)
    org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:100)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:222)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:153)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:165)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.example.demo.core.db.models.Tenant.tenantMembers, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:579)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:203)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:144)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.size(PersistentBag.java:261)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:102)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:672)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:678)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase._serializeWithObjectId(BeanSerializerBase.java:600)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:148)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:130)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1428)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:930)
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:265)
    org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:100)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:222)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:153)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:165)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Stack trace for issue 2: (EDITED)

```
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
    org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57)
    org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2827)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3398)
    org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:597)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:232)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:213)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:256)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:318)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:275)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:113)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.saveTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:254)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:234)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:172)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:853)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:835)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$6.cascade(CascadingActions.java:260)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:391)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:316)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:155)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:424)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:356)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:319)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:155)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:104)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:445)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:238)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:172)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:68)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:843)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:825)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:830)
    com.example.demo.core.db.repos.base.impl.BaseRepoImpl.save(BaseRepoImpl.java:80)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.save(Unknown Source)
    com.example.demo.web.controllers.TenantsController.test(TenantsController.java:30)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'tenant_id' cannot be null
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:932)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2551)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2009)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5094)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1994)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
    org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57)
    org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2827)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3398)
    org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:597)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:232)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:213)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:256)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:318)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:275)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:113)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.saveTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:254)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:234)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:172)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:853)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:835)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$6.cascade(CascadingActions.java:260)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:391)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:316)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:155)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:424)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:356)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:319)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:155)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:104)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:445)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:238)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:172)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:68)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:843)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:825)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:830)
    com.example.demo.core.db.repos.base.impl.BaseRepoImpl.save(BaseRepoImpl.java:80)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.save(Unknown Source)
    com.example.demo.web.controllers.TenantsController.test(TenantsController.java:30)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: And the error stack trace is...

Comment: updated the strack traces for both issues in the question above, thanks

Comment: The second stack trace should have a "caused by" sub-trace containing the error from the database. The first question has been asked a million times: the JSON marshaller tries to marshal the tenantMembers collection, but this collection hasn't been initialized while the session was opened. So you get that exception.

Comment: added the subtrace too...


private String email; (TenantDetails) was missing in the question above... added it..

How do I solve the first question? hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true solves it, but not a good solution I think

Comment: the second question is also not working, i don't understand why it is giving such an error "Field 'email' doesn't have a default value"

Comment: Probably because one of your table has an email column that you didn't map in the corresponding entity. So Hibernate doesn't specify any value in its insert statement for this entity, and MySQL complains because there is no default value specified for this column. Turn the SQL logging on, to see which SQL query fails.

Comment: To solve the first question, make sure to initialize the collection (by calling Hibernate.initialize(), or simply calling any method of the collection, like size()). But I hate returning entities from a REST endpoint. That ties the REST API to the persistent entities, couples the entities with the JSON serialization concerns, causes lazy-loading and maintenance problems. I simply design DTO classes and transform entities into these DTOs. And same for inputs: I accept command DTOs from the browser, and then find/create the entities.

Comment: You are right, its better to use DTOs, I am getting confused with the JSON serialization issues. Thanks a lot.

Regarding the second question: the 'email' column was missing in TenantMembers class- turned up in the SQL logs.
(Still it is showing Column 'tenant_id' cannot be null)
Parent / children will not be saved at one go when i do
tenantRepo.save(tenant) ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help :)
... I'm now trying if parent/children can be saved at one go using tenantRepo.save(tenant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to question 1 :
The following does not fit exactly to you usage of @JsonIgnore an the child reference to Tenant.

But it explains exactly why you get the first exception I think.

You are returning an instance of Tenant from your controller. 
Tenant.tenantMembers is a lazy collection.
When you read Tenant from the tenantRepo, the collection Tenant.tenantMembers is not loaded, because its lazy.
Spring opens a transaction before entering tenantRepo.get(id) and closes it after it. When the transaction is closed, the hibernate session is also closed and the empty collection Tenant.tenantMembers can not be loaded.
Jackson tries to convert Tenant to JSON and tries to read Tenant.tenantMembers. Because there is no session, in this moment the Exception is thrown

```
com.example.demo.core.db.models.Tenant.tenantMembers, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

When you add @JsonIgnore on tenantMembers Jackson will not touch that field and you dont get the exception.

To overcome this, you have to fetch Tenant.tenantMembers EAGER, not LAZY.
This does not make your app slower, because you have to read the whole collection anyways to return it as JSON.
The easisest way to achive this is to change

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "tenant", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch =    
FetchType.EAGER)
private List<TenantMember> tenantMembers;
```

But this may not be what you want, if you want to fetch LAZY in other situations.
You can also create a TenatService with a method get(Long id) that you annotate ax @Transactional.
Inside the get(..) method you do

Tenant tenant = tenantRepo.get(id);
   tenant.getTenantMembers().size();

When you enter the get(..) method spring opens a new transaction (because of @Transactional), read from the repository in the same transaction.
Calling size() on the collection will load it and because the transaction is still open, hibernate will do that.
When get(..) is left, spring closes the transaction but this is no problem because the collection is already initialized.
Thats it.

to question 2
In the code provided I cannot find the cause of that Exception.
I would suggest to set a breakpoint at

```
  com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2551)
```

to see, what exactly happens.
There , or a little up the stack you will see the entity that hibernate wants to write. Normally this gives you more information of whats going wrong.
In the stacktrace you see ActionQueue, which is used by hibernate to write  to the database at the end of a transaction. This happens, when the transaction is closed and not directly when your save(..) is executed.
Hope that helps.

**regarding comment :  @Transactional, and calling size() but it does not work- got the same error. (exception thrown before calling size() itself)...**

Hi kukkuz, there may be reasons to get an exception, but that you get the same HttpMessageNotWritableException sounds very unlikely. Serialization will happen much later, so it is near to impossible to recevive that exception before calling .size().

Actually the stacktrace shows,that the exception is thrown when the request left the controller method and spring tries to serialize the result to JSON.

You must call .size() inside the service method that is annotated as transactional. Set a breakpoint there, you should see a spring proxy in your stacktrace just before the call to your service method. If not this shows that your transaction management does not work.
You also may have to use a service interface, depending on the configuration/version spring will only create proxies for interfaces.
Please publish the stacktrace of that exception to find the exact reason.

**regarding comment  : For question 2, have updated the stack trace....**

In the stacktrace you see that hibernate tries to save a one to one relationship :

```
org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:391)
```

So the problem must be how this relationship mis defined :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "tenant", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

private List tenantMembers;

I think you have the mappedBy on the wrong end.

From [jpa one to one](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html) :

> If the relationship is bidirectional, the non-owning side must use the mappedBy

And you have it on the non owning side.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation...
Using EAGER on List<TenantMember> works....

But on FETCH,  I tried your solution of using @Transactional, and calling size() but it does not work- got the same error. (exception thrown before calling size() itself)....

Comment: For question 2, have updated the stack trace in the question (there was a typo issue in my entity that @JB Nizet pointed out when I ran and pasted the stacktrace here- pasted the correct stacktrace now). Could you pls check?